# How to modify a form field?

Tags: ajax, webforms, forms

i want to modify a Select option field of webform with hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(), but when I do something like:

```
$form['submitted']['dia'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => 'Dia',
'#options' => $options_first,
'#default_value' => $selected,
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
),
);
```

all the other values are replaced and also the weight.

I only need to add `'options'`, `'default_value'`, and `'ajax'`. If I remove other properties like, 'type' the field is not displayed, and the other properties like weight is removed if I do what is in the code. How to modify these 3 attributes?

Comment: All the other values == other fields are affected? or what exactly is the problem? And what parts you need to change, exactly?

Comment: @Mołot I only need to add 'options', 'default_value', and 'ajax', if I remove other properties like, 'type' the field is not displayed, and the other properties like weight is removed if I do what is in the code.

Comment: I edited your question for you, but next time please do it yourself :) Edit is a way to provide more data, not comments. Comment only to ping people that you have updated your question.

Comment: Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc. that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using this syntax:

```
$form['submitted']['dia'] = array(
```

you create a whole new array, with only the values you provided. Old array that was there is simply discarded. If you only want to add or modify `'options'`, `'default_value'`, and `'ajax'`, you need to access them directly:

```
$form['submitted']['dia']['options'] = $options_first;
$form['submitted']['dia']['default_value'] = $selected;
$form['submitted']['dia']['ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
);
```